# Add an attribute to the XML Column from another column in the same/another table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, sqlxml

Here's my scenario:

```
--ORDER table
OrderID OrderCode DateShipped    ShipmentXML
1       ABC       08/06/2013     <Order><Item CustomerName="BF" City="Philadelphia" State="PA"></Item></Order>
2       XYZ       08/05/2013     <Order><Item CustomerName="TJ" City="Richmond" State="VA"></Item></Order>
```

At some point in the process, I will know the respective TrackingNumber for these Orders. The tracking numbers are available in another table like this:

```
 --TRACKING table
 TrackingID    OrderCode   TrackingNumber    
 98            ABC         1Z1               
 99            XYZ         1Z2
```

The output I'm expecting is as below:

```
   OrderID OrderCode     ShipmentXML
   1       ABC           <Order><Item CustomerName="BF" City="Philadelphia" State="PA" DateShipped="08/06/2013" TrackingNumber="1Z1"></Item></Order>
   2       XYZ           <Order><Item CustomerName="TJ" City="Richmond" State="VA" DateShipped="08/05/2013" TrackingNumber="1Z2"></Item></Order>`
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get the `TrackingNumber` and the `DateShipped` for each `OrderCode` and have them as an attribute. The intent is a SELECT, not UPDATE.

All the examples I've seen demonstrate how to update the XML with a Constant value or a variable. I couldn't find one that demonstrates XML updates with a JOIN. Please help with how this can be accomplished.

UPDATE:

By 'Select not Update', I meant that no updates to the permanent table; UPDATE on temp tables are perfectly fine, as Mikael commented below the first answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A version using a temp table to add the attributes to the XML.

```
select OrderID,
       OrderCode,
       DateShipped,
       ShipmentXML
into #Order
from [Order]

update #Order
set ShipmentXML.modify
  ('insert attribute DateShipped {sql:column("DateShipped")} 
    into (/Order/Item)[1]')

update O
set ShipmentXML.modify
  ('insert attribute TrackingNumber {sql:column("T.TrackingNumber")} 
    into (/Order/Item)[1]')
from #Order as O
  inner join Tracking as T
    on O.OrderCode = T.OrderCode

select OrderID,
       OrderCode,
       ShipmentXML
from #Order

drop table #Order
```

Comment: +1 to this also. The more various approaches the richer choice in particular situation.

Comment: @i-one The advantage with this approach is that the XML can have any number of other nodes in it and they will still be there in the result. Yours and the other answer both rebuilds the XML assuming that what is in the question is all there is. And it might very well be so, only OP knows.

Comment: +1, yes it could be useful if XML is richer than one in the question

Comment: @MikaelEriksson You are absolutely correct; the Xml is very likely grow with other nodes in future.

Answer (score 3):

Prevous answer is good, but you have to explicitly specify columns and cast them into varchar, and that's not good for future support (if you add attributes to ShipmentXML you'll have to modify the query).
Instead, you could use XQuery:

```
select
    O.OrderID, O.OrderCode,
    (
        select
            (select O.DateShipped, T.TrackingNumber for xml raw('Item'), type),
            O.ShipmentXML.query('Order/*')
        for xml path(''), type
    ).query('<Order><Item>{for $i in Item/@* return $i}</Item></Order>')
from [ORDER] as O
    left outer join [TRACKING] as T on T.OrderCode = O.OrderCode
```

or even like this:

```
select
    O.OrderID, O.OrderCode,
    O.ShipmentXML.query('
            element Order {
                element Item {
                    attribute DateShipped {sql:column("O.DateShipped")},
                    attribute TrackingNumber {sql:column("T.TrackingNumber")},
                    for $i in Order/Item/@* return $i
                }
            }')
from [ORDER] as O
    left outer join [TRACKING] as T on T.OrderCode = O.OrderCode
```

see [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9cc5/2) with examples

Comment: Both clever ways of rebuilding the XML. +1.

Comment: My +1 also, I'm not familiar with these techniques yet

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know allowing partial modification of data in columns of `xml` type is using `modify` method, but as stated in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx)

> The modify() method of the xml data type can only be used in the SET
>   clause of an UPDATE statement.

Since `UPDATE` is not desired, as a workaround I see shredding and reassembling it manually as:

```
select
    o.OrderID,
    o.OrderCode,
    (
        cast((select
            t.c.value('@CustomerName', 'varchar(50)') as '@CustomerName',
            t.c.value('@City', 'varchar(50)') as '@City',
            t.c.value('@State', 'varchar(50)') as '@State',
            o.DateShipped as '@DateShipped',
            tr.TrackingNumber as '@TrackingNumber'
        for xml path('Item'), root('Order')) as xml)
    ) as ShipmentXML
from
    [ORDER] o
    join [TRACKING] tr on tr.OrderCode = o.OrderCode
    cross apply o.ShipmentXML.nodes('Order/Item') t(c)
```

You may have to apply formatting to `o.DateShipped`.

Comment: Or you could extract the rows to a temp table and modify the XML there (twice) and then query the temp table. +1

Comment: i-one & @Mikael please see edit to the question. I'd love to see  Mikael's approach as well.

Comment: @FMFF I added a version that does that.