# Project relational data to XML column - is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, xml, projection

I have 2 tables of the following structure:

```
People

Id | LastName | FirstName | Other columns...
```

The second table has an XML column:

```
Id | MyXmlCol | Other columns...
```

`MyXmlCol` stores the following XML:

```
<myData>
  <block>
    <person id="1" />
    ...other nodes
  </block>
  ...other blocks
</myData>
```

The id attribute points actually to the Id column of the People table.

What I need, is to query `MyXmlCol`, so that it returns:

```
<myData>
  <block>
    <person id="1" LastName="Jones" FirstName="Bob" />
    ...other nodes
  </block>
  ...other blocks
</myData>
```

Is it possible to make such projection?
I'm using Sql Server 2012.

Comment: If your intention is only show xml in this form without changing the underlying data stored in xml column, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091101/add-an-attribute-to-the-xml-column-from-another-column-in-the-same-another-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there can be only one element "person" in a single element "block", this should suit:

```
update T
set MyXmlCol.modify('
    insert (
        attribute LastName {sql:column("P.LastName")},
        attribute FirstName {sql:column("P.FirstName")}
    )
    into (/myData/block/person)[1]')
from @Table2 T
inner join @People P on T.MyXmlCol.value('(/myData/block/person/@id)[1]', 'int') = P.Id
```

Comment: Can I use `sql:column` with SQL parameters? (I need to insert new `block` elements). I tried `DECLARE @updXml XML; SET @updXml = '<block><person id="id_goes_here" lastName="{ sql:column("People.LastName") }" /></block>` and then use `@updXml` variable in `insert` statement, but in this case XML seems to be invalid (I'm getting `Msg 9410 whitespace expected`)

Comment: You can use sql:column only within a select statement. Try this: `DECLARE @updXml XML = '', @Id INT = 1, @LastName VARCHAR(100);
SELECT @LastName = LastName FROM @People WHERE Id = @Id;
SET @updXml = @updXml.query('<block><person id="{sql:variable("@Id")}" lastName="{sql:variable("@LastName")}" /></block>');` Or you may generate all the block at a time: `SELECT Id AS '@id', LastName AS '@lastName' FROM @People FOR XML PATH('person'), TYPE, ROOT('block')`